# How to cast a variable in an R.array.* reference?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

so I'm trying to do an if/then statement, and having the result being either R.array.measurements or R.array.currency. Both "measurements" and "currency" refers to two arrays in the strings.xml file. It expects an integer value so I tried parsing as an Integer but it's not working.

What I'm trying to do is if isMeasurement == false then display the ListView as the measurements list, and if isMeasurement == true then it'll show the currency list. Everything else as far as I know works. Thanks for any help :)

This is what I've tried:

```
private String unitType;
    Boolean isMeasurement = false;
            if(isMeasurement){
                unitType = "R.array.measurements"; 
            } else {
                unitType = "R.array.currency";
            }
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, Integer.parseInt(unitType), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

This is my original code:

```
private String unitType;
    Boolean isMeasurement = false;
            if(isMeasurement){
                unitType = "R.array.measurements";
            } else {
                unitType = "R.array.currency";
            }
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.measurements, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Comment: Just make unitType an int. You cannot parse a String to an int ***unless the String itself is an int***  and only contains numbers. You have a String literal with R.array.measurements, not a String with the value of R.array.measurements. But you still forgot to create a [mcve]

Comment: Ah ok. Is there an example you could give or a site you could link that I could look it up? Also, is there more of the code that I need to show? I'm not I understand the Minimal Complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `getResourses().getString(R.array.measurements);`? This will get you the actual value of R.array.measurements. Right now you're just assigning a string literal.

Alternatively, if you need the integer value, then `R.array.measurements` without quotes will give you the integer ID.